# Removing an item from an array using index in vue JS returns an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, array-splice

So I have the following array:

```
var hdr = ("name", "date", "start_time", "selling_item", "total_call", 
           "end_time", "ad_num", "area", "order_num");
//this data is returned from db
```

Now I want to replace it with proper naming convention, so I do this:

```
renameTableHdr(hdrs){
        var handler = hdrs;

        for(var a = 0; a<hdrs.length; a++){
            // console.log(hdrs[a]);
            var itm = "";
            if(hdrs[a] === 'name'){
                itm = "Name";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'ad_num'){
                itm = "Ad Number";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'date'){
                itm = "Date";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'order_num'){
                itm = "Order Number";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'start_time'){
                itm = "Start Time";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'area'){
                itm = "Area";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'selling_item'){
                itm = "Selling Item";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'end_time'){
                itm = "End Time";
            }
            if(hdrs[a] === 'total_call'){
                itm = "Total Call";
            }

            if(handler.indexOf(hdrs[a]) >= 0){
                handler.splice(handler.indexOf(hdrs[a]),1);
            }
            this.tempTblHdr.push(itm);
        }
    },
```

So if I'm not doing splice, data returned is correct or the expected one. But with splice, it's not doing it well.

**Result without splice**

```
(9) ["Ad Number", "Date", "Order Number", "Start Time", "Name", "Area", "Selling Item", "End Time", "Total Call", __ob__: Observer]
```

**With Splice**

```
(5) ["Ad Number", "Order Number", "Name", "Selling Item", "Total Call", __ob__: Observer]
//other 4 data are missing
```

I'm removing this items from `handler` for they are the main needed data that is needed to be in proper naming convention, and there's possibility that it is added. I'm renaming them without touching or changing their indexes. Am I doing the `splice` correctly?

Comment: you are changing the length in the loop

Comment: Why don't you just assign it back, like `hrds[a] = itm`?

Comment: @HMR Edited. I am testing it in my end, and copied the edited one.

Comment: You can translate this easier using a translate object: `const translated = {name:'Name'};const hdrs = handler.map(item=>translated[item]);`

Comment: Since handler and hdrs refer to the same object you will mutate both if you mutate one.

Comment: @HMR Will it remove the item from the array? for I still have to check if there're remaining items because there's possibility that there will be an added item like `address`,`code` and etc.

Comment: @HMR Oh I see, how can I resolve it?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would pass an array to a function and have that function mutate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the translation in the following way by not mutating or using for loops:

```js
function renameTableHdr(hdrs) {
  // console.log(hdrs[a]);
  const translate = {
    name: 'Name',
    ad_num: 'Ad Number',
    date: 'Date',
    order_num: 'Order Number',
    start_time: 'Start Time',
    area: 'Area',
    selling_item: 'Selling Item',
    end_time: 'End Time',
    total_call: 'Total Call',
    'things with spaces':'Translates fine'
  };
  return hdrs.map((item) => translate[item] || "");
}

console.log(
  renameTableHdr([
    'name',
    'date',
    'start_time',
    'selling_item',
    'total_call',
    'end_time',
    'ad_num',
    'area',
    'order_num',
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'things with spaces',
  ]),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this man. Better and more efficient way. So time saving (phew)

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an item from an array, you should do it backwards. The reason for this, is the index keeps growing, even if you deleted the item.

Hence, if I do:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array.splice(i, 1));
}
```

The first time it goes in, `i` equals `0`, so it evaluates `array[0]` (so the element `"a"`) and removes it from the array.

On the second iteration, `i` will be `1`, and since my array is now `["b", "c", "d"]`, `array[i]` will be `"c"`.

After skipping `"b"` and removing `"c"`, the array will be `["b", "d"]`. On the third iteration, `i` will be `2`, and since that's the array, `2` is greater than `array.length`, it will stop there.

If you do it backwards, it removes `"d"`first, then `"c"` and so on, meaning it doesn't skip anything.

Since you are worried about your indexing, just add the items from the start with `unsifht`:

```
  renameTableHdr(hdrs){
    var handler = hdrs;

    for(var a = hdrs.length-1; a>=0; a--){
      // console.log(hdrs[a]);
      var itm = "";

      if(hdrs[a] === 'name'){
        itm = "Name";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'ad_num'){
        itm = "Ad Number";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'date'){
        itm = "Date";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'order_num'){
        itm = "Order Number";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'start_time'){
        itm = "Start Time";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'area'){
        itm = "Area";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'selling_item'){
        itm = "Selling Item";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'end_time'){
        itm = "End Time";
      }
      if(hdrs[a] === 'total_call'){
        itm = "Total Call";
      }

      if(handler.indexOf(hdrs[a]) >= 0){
        handler.splice(handler.indexOf(hdrs[a]),1);
      }
      this.tempTblHdr.unshift(itm);
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this input man! So good to have an explanation, it makes things clearer  :)

Answer (score 1):

When removing item from an array, you should loop backward like this

```
   renameTableHdr(hdrs){
        var handler = hdrs;

        for(var a = hdrs.length - 1; a >= 0; a--){
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TrungDong Yes this solves my problem, but my indexing is now affected. I mean they are now in `9-0` indexing instead of `0-9`.

Comment: Instead of using *push* function, you could try to use *this.tempTblHdr.unshift(itm);*